# Is network manager called from an /etc/init.d script?

Tags: 10.04, network-manager, dhclient

I want to run a script to set the hostname on a heavy customized liveUSB version of ubuntu 10.04 (customized means I'm not ready to update to latest version)

I need the script to run before the network manager calls dhclient.  Where is network manager invoked in the /etc/rc.d scripts?  If I add a script with update-rc.d with priority 05, will the script run before network manager invokes dhclient?

Answer (score -1):

You can add your script to `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/`

Comment: That sounded like the ideal solution until I found that the script I put in that directory wasnt being executed, then I read that network manager won't execute scripts placed there.  Is there a solution for when network manager is handling it?

Comment: Found the answer:  putting the script into /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d worked!